# What is the difference between the various log messaging severity levels?

Tags: 7, debugging

There are several types of log messaging severity levels - emergency, critical, error, alert, info, notice, warning, debug. What does each level mean? Example, emergency and critical sound similar, what's the difference? Also, info and notice sound similar.

Answer (score 4):

The code is the best manual :)

```
/**
 * Log message severity -- Emergency: system is unusable.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_EMERGENCY', 0);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Alert: action must be taken immediately.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_ALERT', 1);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Critical conditions.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_CRITICAL', 2);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Error conditions.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_ERROR', 3);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Warning conditions.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_WARNING', 4);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Normal but significant conditions.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_NOTICE', 5);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Informational messages.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_INFO', 6);
/**
 * Log message severity -- Debug-level messages.
 */
define('WATCHDOG_DEBUG', 7);
```

Answer (score 3):

The levels are mostly arbitrary below **alert**, and just represent a general priority of "badness".

In theory, a minimum log level could be set up in core, so that you could enable logging on a live site, but only have certain levels logged (say, emergency, critical, error, and alert) and the rest ignored.  To my knowledge, this hasn't been implemented (I would *love* to be shown wrong about this).

The current usage has more to do with filtering on the recent log messages page (admin/reports/dblog).

Comment: The ability to turn off debug messages on any environment would be good.